# Why has my Fanatic badge's progress been rolled back even if I'm sure I visited the site every day?

Tags: discussion

On Monday 18th of May I was on my 99th day of site visiting streak. I'm pretty sure I visited the site the May 19th, I even have it logged in my web browser's history. Unfortunatelly on May 20th my progress has been rolled back. What could be the possible reason for that?

Actually the same thing happened yesterday when after 2 consecutive days of visiting the site my progress got back to 1 day again today.

May the reason be that I just visited the home page for a too short period of time? I didn't interact with the website that day to be honest.

[image]

Comment: The badge's visit tracking is time-zone specific. I don't know all of the details but I'd wager that's what happened.

Comment: It's also flat out bugged. I was on a 60 day streak, left for a month vacation, and had it when I came back. I am absolutely certain I hadn't visited within several days when it was awarded.

Comment: Regardless of the badge, well done for hitting a 100-day streak! 

Comment: It's easier if you have Stackexchange mobile app, you get a notification when someone comments, you check that adds a day count.

Comment: wow, TIL there is a mobile app, thanks @PranayJaiswal!